# How to enable horizontal scrolling in FullPage.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, fullpage.js

I have a GPA Calculator web application fully operational. I intend for it to be responsive, however it seems as if there are a couple of bugs for smart phones and tablets.

It seems as if for tablets, the content fits like in desktop version, however when you click on a field in zooms in to the page to that specific input. After that, the user has to scroll to the right in order to access all the other input fields...

[image: Tablet Version when filling out the form]

FullPage.js does not allow this type of scrolling, as it automatically slides to the next horizontal page: which is the output section.

I do want my results and the input area to be two different pages, and the only way i knew how without storing data is to have it on one webpage with a slideshow function. Is there a way to enable horizontal scrolling in Fullpage.Js, or disable the slide unless they push a certain button? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Here's the website: http://gpacalc.tk/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    css3: true,
    slidesNavigation: true,
    normalScrollElements: '.slide'

});


$('body').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) { //alternative options for wheelData: wheelDeltaX & wheelDeltaY
      //scroll down
      $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
    } else {
      //scroll up
      $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideLeft();
    }
    //prevent page fom scrolling
    return false;
});
```

With help of "Alvaro" & http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/gWnNv/7/

Comment: This does not work with touchpad. More than 1 slide gets scrolled

Answer (score 1):

Try using the plugin option `normalScrollElements` for the whole section and then just call a function like `moveSlideRight` when clicking in a button.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use css:overflow?

```
 .selector {
      overflow-x: scroll;
 }
```